# Graphing Time in the Y-Axis creates duplicate entries?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I'm trying to create a graph based on Times and Dates and the Times on the Y-AXIS are being created with duplicate values. I attached a screenshot with the problem, the 0:00 can be seen twice.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the scale on the y axis to be from 0.0 to 0.99. That should get rid of the top zero.